# Read named pipe once every time input is written

Tags: fifo

I need to write a bash program that runs commands echoed to a named pipe it reads, but I cannot get it work only when a command is sent. It keeps repeating the last command until a new one is written.

That is:

1. Execute `./read_pipe.sh`
2. It waits until a command is echoed to `pipe` and reads it.
3. It executes the command once. <- What doesn't work. It keeps executing it forever.
4. Repeat from step 2.

My `read_pipe.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
pipe="mypipe"
if [ ! -p $pipe ]; then
  echo 'Creating pipe'
  mkfifo $pipe
fi

while true
do
  if read line <$pipe; then
    COMMAND=$(cat $pipe)
    echo "Running $COMMAND ..."
    # sh -c $COMMAND
  fi
done
```

If I `cat "echo 'Hello World'" > mypipe` the output is this forever:

```
Running "echo 'Hello World'" ...
Running "echo 'Hello World'" ...
Running "echo 'Hello World'" ...
Running "echo 'Hello World'" ...
...
```

How can I run the command once and wait for another echoed command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash
pipe=/path/to/pipe
[ -p "$pipe" ] || mkfifo -m 0600 "$pipe" || exit 1
while :; do
    while read -r cmd; do
        if [ "$cmd" ]; then
            printf 'Running %s ...\n' "$cmd"
            # sh -c "$cmd" sh
        fi
    done <"$pipe"
done
```

It's probably a really bad idea to uncomment the `sh` line though.

Comment: I tried your solution, but It doesn't work properly. It executes the command once, but then your program exits. The intended way is keep executing the script, and when a new command is echoed to `pipe`, execute it.

Comment: Ok, I added a loop around it.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. It executes the command sent to pipe forever until a new one is sent. I want it to be executed only once, and then wait for another command.

Comment: Which is what happens after my latest edit.

Comment: Just tested it: It executes the same command forever. http://imgur.com/a/cmrLS I need to execute it once, and only once each time a command is written to the pipe.

Comment: This is [not what I'm seeing here](http://imgur.com/a/zEmgF). _shrug_

Comment: Sorry @SatoKatsura I've just found the solution: `rm -f pipe && mkfifo pipe`. Now it works correctly. For some reason it was a simple text file. -.-'

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to uncomment the `sh` line?

Answer (score 8):

In your case, you can do simply:

```
tail -f $pipe | sh &
```

no need for loops.